# sfdx-cli npm package install not using the proper sfdx version

Tags: salesforcedx, node.js, versioning, docker

When installing sfdx with npm in a docker (`npm i -g sfdx-cli`),
there is a mismatch between the sfdx version shown by `sfdx --version` and the version used by sfdx commands.

`sfdx --version` show `sfdx-cli/7.31.0 linux-x64 node-v12.13.0` while there is an update available message on `sfdx force:org:create` command.

> ›   Warning: sfdx-cli update available from 7.21.0 to 7.31.0.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably installed sfdx using the installer on the website https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli#

You need to uninstall sfdx, then install it using `npm i sfdx-cli -g`